# I have just installed Visual Studio 2012 and I do not see an option for Find in Source Control > Status

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have just installed Visual Studio 2012 and I do not see an option for viewing all pending changes for all users. I previously did this by selecting on the root in Source Control Exlplorer, and then navigating to File > Source Control > Find in Source Control > Status. This would then show me all pending check ins. Now, I only see the option to Find by Shelveset, Changeset or Label.

How can I see all pending changes for all team members?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This functionality is gained via the TFS Power Tools. I suspect you had it installed on your 2010 version. The 2012 version is here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f

Note that the location is *slightly* changed: File > Source Control > Find > Find by Status...

Comment: Thank You so much,I realized this after I posted :(

Comment: It's worth noting that this is _only_ accessible via right-click in Source Control Explorer, not through the standard File menu in Visual Studio.